# javascript run exe file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of studying some JavaScript code, produced by another developer and I am unclear on some of the terms used in it.

```
monitorApplication("wceport -ind -d  -rn \\\\cms\\civica\\new.rpt", "Address Directory", "wcreport.exe");
```

Can anyone please tell me what is meant by "-ind -d  -rn"? I'm kind of new to javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you kidding man...!! No one can help you with this much information...

Comment: This is not javascript code, I mean these - terms. Try searching for cmd terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ind -d -rn` is not part of Javascript.

These look like command line options to an external program: `wcereport`

Perhaps they are defined there.

I also note that `monitorApplication()` is neither a standard function of Javascript nor something provided by jQuery.

Starting an external application from Javascript within a web browser is practically the definition of a security hole or backdoor.

In nodeJS, a server side Javascript container, it is possible to spawn child processes that run arbitrary programs.

Comment: Thanks.. I found out that it's a Business Objects Viewer for Crystal Reports and it runs inside the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

The called monitorApplication could call active x or simply pass these parameters to server side. Find the method source if any.